# Yii2 how to format <sup> tags in forms and GridView?

Tags: html, yii2, formatting, tags

I have an `attributeLabels` for an attribute that has a `<sup>` tag:

```
public function attributeLabels() {
    return [
        'density' => Yii::t('yii', 'density (kg/dm<sup>3</sup>)'),
    ];
}
```

In the view it looks appropriate, but in the form and in the `GridView` as label it's simply like `(kg/dm<sup>3</sup>)`

I have tried to add `labelOptions` with many different format values to it, but no luck.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'density', ['labelOptions' => ['format' => '(html/text/raw etc.)']])->textInput() ?>
```

Is it possible to make it look like a real `<sup>` (kg/dm<sup>3</sup>) text in the form, and if yes, can you please tell me how? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Call it like that:

```
<?= $model->getAttributeLabel('density'); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'density')->textinput()->label(false) ?>
```

and after that format your template

Edit (better way):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'density', ['labelOptions' => ['label' => $model->getAttributeLabel('density')]])->textinput() ?>
```

Comment: Hi, it's working like a charm in the form, but I have no clue how to fix the `gridView`. If I'm using `'header' => $searchModel->getAttributeLabel('density')` then it looks good, but I have no sorting. Could you point me to the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to give it like that: `'label' => $searchModel->getAttributeLabel('density'),`

Comment: I have tried that one already, unfortunately it's giving `(kg/dm<sup>3</sup>)`